# Expo is not running

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, expo

When I am running my expo app, I am getting this warning: Warning: Problem validating app.json: Unable to perform cache refresh for C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Expo\schema-37.0.0.json: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JZjF.jpg)

I tried to ignore this warning, and run the app on Android emulator, but then I am getting this error: Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: unable to get local issuer certificate
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjYxy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the Android emulator opened, then you can open the project on it.

Comment: the android emulator is already opened when I ran the project